# Pyspark - Get list of all the tables for given view

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks

We have a few views which is created on top of other few views and so on. I want to know find all the tables and their path which is consumed by these views. However, not able to figure out how to do that.

Initially I thought to parse the `Query Plan` and get this information. However, I am not able to get the full path when I parse the plan.

```
plan = spark.sql("explain extended select * from database.table")
```

type of plan is `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame = [plan: string]`

Then I converting that into string and parsing for location. However, location does not contains the whole path.

```
plan_str = df.select("plan").rdd.map(lambda r:  r[0]).collect()[0]
loc = re.search(r'InMemoryFileIndex\[(.*)\]', plan_str, re.IGNORECASE)

if loc:
    print(loc.group(1))
```

**Output**

> adl://abc.azuredatalakestore.net/informationmart/database..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters:

And following doesn't return anything, it just prints on console.

```
plan = spark.sql("select * from database.table").explain(true)
```

Comment: however what? This was also my first thought. If you're having Hive views you should be able to parse it

Comment: @paul the views are multilevel (i. e view which join two views and those views joins table or views) and contains multiple tables underneath.

Comment: Don't you also get some lines saying `HiveTableScan (....)` when you do `df.explain()`?

Comment: it doesn't give me the full path.

Comment: Strange. For me it does, my output looks like this ``` HiveTableScan [col1#145L, col2#144], HiveTableRelation `my_db`.`my_table`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde, [col2#144], [col1#145L], [isnotnull(col1#145L), (col1#145L = 4)]```

Comment: @Paul yeah. I get those output. However the part I am intersted is. Path. which is after `InMemoryFileIndex`, And When I try to get that through regex, I only get half the path. Not sure why ?